# Derivative of trace of antisymmetrical Matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus

it is easy to show that the derivative of the trace $Tr(A)$ with respect to $A$ if A is a N x N matrix, is

$\frac{\partial Tr(A)}{\partial A} = I_{N \times N}$

However, if I now assume A to be antisymmetric $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ the trace $Tr(A) = 0$ but
with above result the derivative would still be $I_{N \times N}$ and not $= 0$.

In principle the above solution should not be depend on what properties $A$ has. Yet it seems like it does.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems like the situation is analogous to the following: "the function $f(x) = x$ has a derivative of $1$, but if I assume that $x = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$". I don't see anything strange about either situation.

Comment: Or, perhaps you'd find this analogy more apt: "the function $f(x,y) = x + y$ has a gradient of $(1,1)$, but if I assume that $x = -y$ then $f(x,y) = 0$".

Comment: Its much simpler if you note that $\mathrm{tr}(A)={A^i}_i={A^j}_i \delta^i_j$. Then $d\mathrm{tr}(A)=\delta^i_j d{A^j}_i$
and therefore $\partial \mathrm{tr}(A)/\partial A=\delta^i_j$ for all $A$ (a bit like $dx/dx=1$ even when $x=0$).

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\lambda} \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$The utility of the gradient $(G)$ is that it can estimate (via a $\o^{st}$ order Taylor series) the change in the function $(f)$ which results from a small change $(dA)$ in the matrix argument $(A)$
$$\eqalign{
f\LR{A+dA} &= f\LR{A} \;&+\; \trace{G^TdA} \\
\trace{A+dA} &= \trace{A} \;&+\; \trace{dA} \\
}$$
where the last line sets $f\LR{A}=\trace{A}\,$ and $\,G=I,\:$
i.e. your particular function.

If both $A$ and $dA$ are skew symmetric,
then all of the terms in the Taylor series are zero
$$\eqalign{
\trace{A} = \trace{dA} = 0 \qiq \trace{A+dA} = 0 \\
}$$
However, suppose you decide to explore a matrix direction $(dA)$ that is **not skew symmetric**. Amazingly, the Taylor series will **still** give you the correct estimate for this situation
$$\eqalign{
\trace{A+dA} &= \trace{dA} \\
}$$
What if $dA$ is skew symmetric but $A$ isn't? Guess what, the Taylor series remains valid
$$\eqalign{
\trace{A+dA} &= \trace{A} \\
}$$
And if **neither** $A$ nor $dA$ are skew symmetric, the Taylor series continues to work its magic
$$\eqalign{
\trace{A+dA} &= \trace{A} \;+\; \trace{dA} \\
\\
}$$

---

Please note, I'm not poking fun at your question. In fact, I think it's a very important question. I'm just trying to emphasize that (as you suspected) the gradient $(G=I)\,$ **doesn't** depend on the symmetric properties of $A$.

Comment: +1 More generally, this [paper by Panda & Srinivasan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06491.pdf) drives a stake through the heart of the idea that $\large\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A}$ somehow depends upon the symmetry (or skew symmetry or other structural properties) of the $A$ matrix.